# Highcharts - My nice thin cross hair changes to a thick green cross hair when adding categories

Tags: highcharts

I am adding data from an API, and have a nice thin cross hair when not defining categories:

```
chartOptions.series[0]data = [1,2,4,5,7,8];
```

[image]

but when I define categories as well:

```
chartOptions.series[0]data = [1,2,4,5,7,8];
chartOptions.xAxis.categories = ['jan','feb','march','april','may','june']
```

my cross hair is a thick green band:

[image]

I would like to understand why the cross hair is changing like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Highcharts API we can read:

> **width: number**
>
> The pixel width of the crosshair. Defaults to 1 for numeric or datetime axes, and for one category width for category axes.

So, change the `width` property if you want to have different result:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june'],
    crosshair: {
        width: 1,
        color: '#000'
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ps18y3v5/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair.width